# Can I access state values from children components in an array?

Tags: reactjs, reference, state, children

I'm very new to React, in the process of learning it for a school project. I've tried searching for this answer thinking it'd be a fairly simple solution, but I'm having trouble finding a result that matches my scenario.

Essentially I'm looking to have an array of a specific component (e.g. Child), each holding a value in their state (e.g. { value: 2 } ). I'm looking to iterate through the array, accessing each component's state.value, and calculate a total from it.

My initial thought was to hold the array in the parent's state, and then iterate through the array doing something like this:

```
this.state.children.map(child => (
    child.state.value
))
```

However, the result is coming back as 'value' being undefined, leading me to believe I can't access another component's state this way.

I also looked into using refs, as described in the following article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-access-childs-state-in-react/

However, it seems as though that only lets me create a reference to a single child, meaning I would need a new reference for every child component in the array.

Any advice or sample code of what I could do (the more basic the better) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `item` in your code? Not supposed to be child instead?

Comment: Sorry, yes it was meant to be child. I changed some variable names for this post, but I missed that one. Thank you for catching it.

Comment: Wouldn't redux solve this type of issues?

Comment: If it's possible you can save the state in your parent component and modify it from children.

Comment: I'm planning to have around 38 of the children components, but I want the number to be dynamic, which is why I was hoping to iterate through the array. Redux sounds a lot more complicated than what I'm trying to do, but it's possible that's the standard way of doing it. As for the children modifying the parent state, I'm trying to avoid that since it sounds prone to its own complications. I essentially just want a button in the parent component that will calculate the total of the children when pressed.